# Angular Valuechanges not firing first time

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I have a input button, where onChange, I am calling a function. In that funtion, I am checking for valueChanges. Somehow, the subscribe to the valueChanges is not getting triggered on the first tab out after inputting a value.

Here are some code snippets:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" formControlName='{{subControl.name}}' 
(change)="fetchData(subControl.name, 
 true)"/>
```

TS:

```
public fetchData(formControlName: string, fetchData: boolean): void {
if (this.primaryControls.indexOf(formControlName) !== -1 && 
   fetchData) {
  this.uiForm.get(formControlName)?.valueChanges **//fine till here. Gets executed**
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(1000)
    )
    .subscribe(data => { **// This subscribe is not firing**
      if (!this.uiForm.dirty) {
        return;
      }
         //do some stuff here
     }});
```

Comment: Is the form control not defined at this point?
If you console.log(this.uiform.get(formControlName)) is it undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time your input changes, you are creating a new subscription. Nothing happens at first because no subscriptions exist yet.

Just subscribe to `valueChanges` once on init. Use a loop if you have multiple.

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.uiForm.get(this.subControl.name)?.valueChanges.pipe(...).subscribe(...);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" formControlName='{{subControl.name}}'/>
```

I'm assuming `subControl` is a component property, which might not be true. But I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [startWith()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/startWith) with some initial value inside your pipe to fire the subscription the first time.
You can optionally include [distinctUntilChanged()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinctUntilChanged) in the pipe as well.

```
this.uiForm.get(this.formControlName)?.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000), distinctUntilChanged(), startWith(this.uiForm.get(this.formControlName).value)).subscribe(...);
```